# How to open .cfg file on iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I have downloaded a `.cfg` file from
Windows 7 that I want to open in iOS. Are there any apps that will allow me to read the contents of this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.cfg` is a config file for programs, saved in plain text, used in Windows.

---

To view on iOS simply...

1. Install [iFile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifile-free-cloud-file-manager-document-reader-and-viewer/id908003044?mt=8)
2. Transfer the file to your iOS Device (Easiest is via iCloud)
3. Open iFile
4. Import into iFile (For iCloud: Navigate to Clouds>iCloud>Select File)

6.Go to Files

7.Tap on the file to view

[image]

---

To edit (and/or view) simply...

1. Rename `file.cfg` to `file.cfg.txt`
2. Transfer the file to your iOS Device (Easiest is via iCloud)
3. Install [Textor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textor/id1330406995?mt=8)
4. Open the file in Textor and edit

[image]

---

**Note**: I am not affiliated with any of the apps above and will not gain financially or otherwise from the purchasing/downloading/using of these apps. They were merely suggestions.

Comment: Hey thanks, but I'm trying to open it in iOS not windows.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Those instructions are for iOS.

Comment: The file already in the iOS device. How am I supposed to rename a file in iOS?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid See updated answer.

Comment: Hmm using iCloud import works kind of. it opens the file but there is nothing there. It just opens up a page that says FILES and there is nothing else to do or see.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid You need to install iFile. iFile is different from Files.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Glad I could help :)